# Recoloring pixels in a bitmap using 'lookup table'

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

ello,

I am looking for the most efficient way to do the following:

Take an input image in bitmap form, inputIMG. Map each pixel from the
input image, inputIMG(x,y), to a new value using a lookup table,
lookupTable, which is basically an 256x3 element array.

If the input pixel is valued at RGB [192,123,154] the output pixel
value would be the value at lookupTable(192,123,154).

I can easily code this going through the input bitmap pixel by pixel using Bitmap.setPixel(), but there would likely be a lot of overhead associated with that approach due to many repeated calls and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to set each pixel individually you have two options.

One is to set patches of pixels at the same time with `setPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)`:

The other is to create a new bitmap using an array of colors: `createBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)`

Both methods are explained in the [Android Bitmap docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suppose I will use getPixels to pull the data out as an array of integers, operate on each value of the array and create a result bitmap using: createBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)

Comment: Great, if you feel like this answer helped then please consider accepting this as the answer by clicking the checkmark under the upvote/downvote buttons.